# Distro for high end video editing

Tags: linux, rhel

Which distro would be most suited for maximizing hardware to perform expensive video editing and optimize resources.

I followed up with optimizing resources, as in some cases one operation may not be able to make use of available resources, but would know to delegate work concurrently for maximum utilization.

Currently considering OpenSuSE or Red Hat

Comment: Do you know what software you want to use?  That might help with an answer.

Comment: Not yet, But I will most probably handle encoding in ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it but the only distribution I know of that is specifically targeted to video and audio production is [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/):

> Ubuntu Studio is a free and open source operative system, and an official flavor of Ubuntu. Ubuntu Studio is the most widely used multimedia orientated GNU/Linux distribution in the world. It comes preinstalled with a selection of the most common free multimedia applications available, and is configured for best performance for the Ubuntu Studio defined workflows: Audio, Graphics, Video, Photography and Publishing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was planning to stay away from anything ubuntu due to the people around be saying it seems to be getting worse, Along with Richard Stallman advised against using it, labelling it as spyware. Is this part of the same backend?

Comment: @cecilli0n I dislike Ubuntu for many of the same reasons, nevertheless, as far as I know, this Ubuntu flavor is the only distro geared towards what you want to do. That said, any distro will be able to handle it if you set it up right.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your honest opinion. If that's the case I will focus on the config specifics of some other distro, Maybe Red Hat,openSuSu or arch linux.

Comment: I hate to say this, but you do realize that Linux is really not the best OS for this kind of thing right? In any case, what you are looking for is not so much a distro but a kernel that is optimized for your task. The distro will be pretty much irrelevant unless it has modified its kernel accordingly.

Comment: No I didn't realize that, However I will be using multiple programming languages like php,perl,C++ and some other tools like mysql. With regards to what you said, do you know a OS absolutely developed just for video editing? I wasn't aware there was such a thing. However regardless of that, because of my other needs its probably best to get a build which can handle normal day to day programming/pc activities, whilst optimizing as much as possible for when I do edit. Thanks

Comment: @cecilli0n well, BeOS was targeted to the multimedia world but that's now defunct. It is being continued in a new form as [Haiku](https://www.haiku-os.org/) but that's still experimental. I have quite a few friends who are film professionals and they all use macs of course. Basically, there is no large corporation that has spent a lot of money into developing serious video editing tools for Linux. This is one of the (few) cases where open source lags behind proprietary software unfortunately.

Comment: OK thanks for the help, you've answered the question I guess, With all that being said, I will just have to try to get as much out of a distro as possible, I don't want to continue to use windows, The time is now to move away from that platform.

Answer (score 1):

How about Dream Studio? But I also think its based on Ubuntu... so, as you mentioned you wouldn't like that a kinda distro... you could try it out though... via LIVE from an USB boot... I used both, Dream Studio and Ubuntu Studio, but - kernel is the base of the problem, cuz even Windows is not that 'good' regarding professional work, cuz these tools that you need are commercial and some not even open sourced for a reason. From Autodesk to Avid, from Adobe thievery to Cubase etc... audio/video/3d tools is bought and paid for you to work with and make money! Isnt it? So, Mac. Yup. Definately. With a big budget for the workstation itself not to mention other HW you need...

EDIT: just a sec ago took a peek at distrowatch: check out 64 Studio. Based on Debian, ladida... being developed to 'fight a match' against workstation vers of Mac and Windows so... worth a look, I know I'll try it out... eventually.. :P

Cheers...

Comment: Consider adding links and documentation which support your suggestions as being viable solutions.